# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot connect Bluetooth to Android phone

Tags: bluetooth, android

This is another variation on the "Activation of network connection failed" problem.  My wifi is working fine. The problem is that when I try to connect my smart phone by Bluetooth, it does it for a few secnds, then drops the connection and gives me the  "Activation of network connection failed".  How can this be fixed, please?

A.

Comment: Did you install bluetoothctl and check for the messages from that? and does it have to be bluetooth? go-mtpfs works great (but does require thethering)

Comment: No. I am using whatever bluetooth came with Ubuntu. Everything worked fine until I upgraded to 18.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why you may not be able to connect to a Bluetooth device, such as a phone or headset.

**Connection blocked or untrusted**

Some Bluetooth devices block connections by default, or require you to change a setting to allow connections to be made. Make sure that your device is set up to allow connections.

**Bluetooth hardware not recognized**

Your Bluetooth adapter or dongle may not have been recognized by the computer. This could be because drivers for the adapter are not installed. Some Bluetooth adapters are not supported on Linux, so you may not be able to get the right drivers for them. In this case, you will probably have to get a different Bluetooth adapter.

**Adapter is not switched on**

Make sure that your Bluetooth adapter is switched on. Open the Bluetooth panel and check that it is not disabled.

**Device Bluetooth connection switched off**

Check that Bluetooth is turned on on the device you are trying to connect to, and that it is discoverable or visible. For example, if you are trying to connect to a phone, make sure that it is not in airplane mode.

**No Bluetooth adapter in your computer**

Many computers do not have Bluetooth adapters. You can buy an adapter if you want to use Bluetooth.

**Also Check the link below**

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-connect-device.html.en

Comment: Thanks.  I admit I am never sure whether all the switches for Bluetooth are on on Ubuntu.  They appear in several places.  Seems not very user-friendly.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem (multiple times) and found the solution [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/bluetooth-doesnt-display-pin-code-for-pairing/8496/3)

Entering `gsettings set org.blueman.general notification-daemon false` in the terminal will tell Blueman not to rely on the Desktop Environment to give an interactive notification, so it will then give you the needed dialog window by another method.

The thread I linked suggests deleting all pairings and rebooting after entering that command but I have not found that to be necessary. Just attempt the pairing again and watch for a notification bubble < click that to open the dialog window where you can confirm the pairing passkey.

Comment: Related threads suggest that this problem appears when we have experimented with desktop themes. Which unfortunately is going to be most of us :(