# Pairing old Nokia to Dell Vostro via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, password, phone

I've been trying to pair my old Nokia phone to my Dell Vostro laptop via Bluetooth to see if I could transfer some photos, but I don't know how to do this.
I enabled Bluetooth on both devices, obviously (and made them visible) and the name of my laptop appears on my phone when I search for devices. I tried to add it as a new device, but my phone prompts for a passkey. I looked all over for a code, but can't find it. I tried a few things like 0000. The name of my phone does not appear in devices, though, although there is an entry "Phone" with the message "not set up", along with a bunch of unknown devices with the same message. These are shown in light grey (you can't click them) and there are no "options".

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The phone is not "smart" in any way, just so you know, although it is one of those models that supposedly connects to wifi as well, but I never got that to work (it was passed on to me).

It's the first time I try to connect via Bluetooth, so it might be something really silly. Does anyone know where I might find such a passkey or if there is something else I must enable? Thanks.

Comment: Probably that "phone" that is not set up is the device you're looking for. Try clicking on it to start the pairing procedure instead of from your phone.

Comment: @ToDo yes, well, I can't click it, it's shown in light grey, just like the unknown devices

Comment: Usually, the passkey is generated on the other device, in your case, the Dell.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to a very similar problem I just answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1374045/785073).

The default Bluetooth GUI in Ubuntu is Blueman. Which apparently relies on an interactive notification method easily broken by those of us who try other desktop themes.
The terminal command `gsettings set org.blueman.general notification-daemon false` tells Blueman to give us the required dialog window by another method.